# How to insert multiple values into a Row if 1 field is distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Right I have the following data which i need to insert into a table called locals but I only want to insert it if the street field is not already present in the locals table. The data and fields are as follows:

```
Street    PC       Locality
------------------------------
Street1   ABC xyz  A
Street2   DEF xyz  B
```

And so on but I want to insert into the Locals table if the Street field is not already present in the locals table.

I was thinking of using the following:

```
INSERT
  INTO Locals (Street,PC,Locality) 
       (
            SELECT DISTINCT s.Street
              FROM Locals_bk s
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                      SELECT 1
                        FROM Locals l
                       WHERE s.Street = l.Street
                   )
       )
     ;
```

But I realize that will only insert the street field not the rest of the data on the same row.

Comment: does locals_bk s and locals have same columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into Locals (Street, PC, Locality) 
select b.Street, b.PC, b.Locality
from Locals_bk as b
where not exists (select * from Locals as t where t.street = b.street)
```

or

```
insert into Locals (Street, PC, Locality) 
select b.Street, b.PC, b.Locality
from Locals_bk as b
where b.street not in (select t.street from Locals as t)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
INSERT [Locals]
SELECT
            [Street],
            [PC],
            [Locality]
    FROM
            [Locals_bk] bk
    WHERE
         NOT EXIST (
             SELECT * FROM [Locals] l WHERE l.[Street] = bk.[Street]
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NOT IN :

```
    INSERT into Locals (Street,PC,Locality) 
    SELECT s.Street, s.PC, s.Locality
    FROM Locals_bk as s
    WHERE NOT IN (SELECT * FROM Locals as t WHERE t.street = s.street)
```

Comment: I think you mean `s.street not in (select t.street from Locals as t)`

Answer (score 0):

The following fetches the needed fields from an arbitrary row that matches the street:

```
insert into Locals (Street, PC, Locality) 
select s.Street, s.PC, s.Locality
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by s.Street order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Locals_bk s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1 and
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Locals l
                  WHERE s.Street = l.Street);
```

If you know the values are always the same, you can just do:

```
insert into Locals (Street, PC, Locality) 
select distinct s.Street, s.PC, s.Locality
from Locals_bk s
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Locals l
                  WHERE s.Street = l.Street);
```